# how to get the width-height of UITableView in custom cell's initWithStyle: method?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have created custom cell in which there are n number of image views. According to number of image views per row, i put the size of the imageview. for that, I need width of the UITableView in initWithStyle: method of the UITableViewCell. But the iPad returns the width of the UITableView as 320. My application is designed for the iPad only and I have put XIB for iPad only (I have checked the option "Targeted for iPad" or like).

Is there any way I can get the width of the tableview from the init method? I have used self.contentView.frame and self.frame but they didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is correct. ;) As soon, as you init a tableRow, it's width is probably 320 by default. You have to use correct autoresizing flags for your imageView to resize automatically. Alternativly you could use the tableView delegate method `willDisplayRow:atIndexPath:` to customize the imageView, after the tableViewRow has been resized to its actual size.

Comment: well..this is not good...I have to set all that again in the willDisplayRow: method.... :(   any way, but thanx for the kind answer.

Comment: no probably you can use autoresizing on your imageView as well. (unless that doesn't fit in your case.. but i think it does)